# Drawing circle with OpenLayers3, but not seeing on map?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, circle

I am trying to draw a circle on a map, using OpenLayers 3, but I am not sure why the circle is not rendering. My expectations with the code below is that is should be centering on -73.5971431341708, 45.5323780468158 (Montreal, Canada) and drawing a circle at that location, with a radius of 1000m.

Below is the code:

```
var baseLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
                    source: new ol.source.OSM()
                });

var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource,
    style: [
    new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'blue',
            width: 3
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)'
        })
    })]
});

/* Example of a low poly circle */
var features = [];
var circle = new ol.geom.Circle([-73.5971431341708, 45.5323780468158], 1000);
circle = circle.clone().transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');;
var precisionCircle = ol.geom.Polygon.circular(
    /* WGS84 Sphere */
    new ol.Sphere(6378137),
    circle.getCenter(),
    circle.getRadius(),
    /* Number of verticies */
    64);

features.push(new ol.Feature({ geometry: precisionCircle }));
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: features
});

var layer2 = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource,
    style: [
    new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'red',
            width: 3
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1)'
        })
    })]
});
var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [baseLayer, layer2],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.transform([-73.5971431341708, 45.5323780468158], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
        zoom: 14,
    }),
    units: 'm'
});
```

I also have a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ajmas/40fcgrh0/5/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var baseLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
                    source: new ol.source.OSM()
                });

var circle = new ol.geom.Circle(ol.proj.transform([-73.5971431341708, 45.5323780468158], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'), 1000);

var CircleFeature = new ol.Feature(circle);


var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
projection: 'EPSG:4326',
});

vectorSource.addFeatures([CircleFeature]);


var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource,
    style: [
    new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'blue',
            width: 3
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)'
        })
    })]
});




var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [baseLayer, layer],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.transform([-73.5971431341708, 45.5323780468158], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
        zoom: 14        
    }),
    units: 'm'
});
```

`ol.geom.Circle` creates a circle on a plane in EPSG:3857, while `ol.geom.Polygon.circular` approximates a circle on the surface of a sphere (in this case it only has 64 vertices so not a great approximation). For a circle of 1000m radius theres not a lot of point in using `ol.geom.Polygon.circular` (maybe if you're near the poles) unless you intend to export the polygon. If you do want to use `ol.geom.Polygon.circular` then creating a circle first is entirely redundant as the center and radius can be set directly. Then you just need to get your projections right, by transforming the polygon from 'EPSG:4326' to 'EPSG:3857'

```
var baseLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

precisionCircle = ol.geom.Polygon.circular(
        /* WGS84 Sphere */
        new ol.Sphere(6378137),
        [-73.5971431341708, 45.5323780468158],
        1000,
        /* Number of verticies */
        64).transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
precisionCircleFeature = new ol.Feature(precisionCircle)
vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector();
vectorSource.addFeature(precisionCircleFeature);
 layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource,
    style: [
        new ol.style.Style({
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: 'red',
                width: 3
            }),
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1)'
            })
        })]
});



 map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [baseLayer, layer],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.transform([-73.5971431341708, 45.5323780468158], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
        zoom: 14
    }),
    units: 'm'
});
```

Comment: Welcome! Please add a little explanation to your answer. Code is good, but having the additional context of what was wrong and why is better.

Comment: The main difference I see is you use 'ol.geom.Circle' directly as the feature instead of using 'ol.geom.Polygon.circular', which doesn't fit with other examples I have seen. So while this does work, I need to be sure I understand if this will have any unintended limitations, given this difference. Also, the projection at the vector layer seems redundant. An explanation would be appreciated.